# Checking for a string/keyword in a list

Tags: python

I am currently doing a piece of code for a game which needs to test whether the player's input contains one or two certain strings. I have tried to make sense of a few explanations but they don't talk about exactly what I need and are quite technical.

So far I have used `.split()` to put the input into a list and then used `if keyword0 and keyword1 in list:` (as I was hoping to make it so two keywords were required) to provoke a response. I think this plan may be flawed so could someone suggest a built-in function or general idea that could be used in some way to achieve this?

Comment: *"I think this plan may be flawed"* - why exactly do you think that? Have you actually *tried anything?* Also, you should note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; I'd recommend taking the [tour] and learning [ask].

Comment: We don't know the explanations either, so we can't help you without more info :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very specific. I intend to use "variable = str(input('What do you do? ')) Then use "list_of_variable = variable.split()" to organise this into a list. This would hopefully be a list containing strings. I would then like to use "if keyword0 and keyword1 in list_of_variable:". I am not in any way pretending to know what I'm doing I'm VERY new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `if keyword0 and keyword1 in list:` syntax is doing what you want. It is checking condition `if keyword0`  and `keyword1 in list`.  `if keyword0` returns true if keyword0 is not `None` or not empty string.

```
if keyword0 in list and keyword1 in list:
    # do your work
    pass
```

OR

```
if all(key in list for key in [keyword0, keyword1]):
    # do your work
    pass
```

Comment: OP is using **or** because he wanted a string containing *both* keywords.

Comment: @Prune thanks for pointing out that. I misunderstood the sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it is exactly what I needed. I am sure this whole process was a bit frustrating since I did not give much info. I'm sure you can tell this is my first time using the site so thanks for being so helpful to everyone who has commented!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
if keyword0 and keyword1 in list:
```

As it effectively evaluates to

```
if (keyword0) and (keyword1 in list):
```

Evaluating `keyword0` as a boolean. Instead, try:

```
if keyword0 in list and keyword1 in list:
```

Note though if you're using `.split()`, then your string tokens will include things like punctuation which may not be what you want. For example

```
>>> items = 'Hello, World!'.split()
>>> items
['Hello,', 'World!']
>>> 'Hello' in items
False
>>> 'Hello,' in items
True
```